# Deployment environments

Tags: java, deployment, production-environment

I have been looking for methods of using same java packagae (.jar) to be deployed on different deployment environments without the need to create a new package for each environment.

Currently I use blade logic to modify the package according to the environment, the process is controlled by writing scripts. is there a way to write only one script for different deployment environments?

Answer (score 0):

You should seperate your enviroments settings apart of code and then use some build tool (`Maven` for example: http://maven.apache.org/) with profile definition for each enviroment. If you decide to use maven you can use

http://code.google.com/p/maven-replacer-plugin/

and

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html